# $\sigma^4=\operatorname{id}$ $\sigma^3(\alpha)+\sigma(\alpha)=\sigma^2(\alpha)+\alpha$ then $\sigma^2=\operatorname{id}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\sigma$ an automorphism of a field $F$ such that $\sigma^4=\operatorname{id}$ and for all $\alpha\in F$ $$\sigma^3(\alpha)+\sigma(\alpha)=\sigma^2(\alpha)+\alpha.$$

Show that $\sigma^2=\operatorname{id}$.

I tried it many hours. I have not idea which is the trick.

Comment: If $\sigma^2 = \mathrm{id}$ and the characteristic of the field is not $2$ then $\sigma^3 + \sigma = \sigma^2 + \mathrm{id}$ reduces to $\sigma = \mathrm{id}$.  So it seems weird to me that a significantly stronger conclusion is so easy to prove from what you're asked to prove.

Comment: Anyway, let $k$ be the fixed field of $\sigma$ and look at the minimal polynomial of $\sigma$ when you consider it as an automorphism of $F$ as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: Ahh, I guess the possibility that the characteristic of the field **is** $2$ is why you can only conclude that $\sigma^2 = \mathrm{id}$.  You can see this from the minimal polynomial argument.  I retract my claim that I think the question is strange. :)

Comment: @ Jim:  would you mind writing that up as an answer?  I for one would like to see the details.  Thanks in advance, Bob Lewis

Comment: @Jim: Is it immediately obvious that the dimension of $F$ over $k$ is finite?

Comment: What's strange about this question is that the second condition implies the first: Apply $\sigma$ to both sides of the equation.

Comment: @tomasz: No, it's not.  But I don't think that matters, does it?

Comment: @RobertLewis: Well, the gist was that the minimum polynomial must divide $x^3 - x^2 + x - 1 = (x^2 + 1)(x - 1)$ but I realize now I was assuming that the minimum polynomial was irreducible.  The only way I can think of for arguing that the minimum polynomial is not $x^3 - x^2 + x - 1$ is to use Artin's theorem, which as Jyrki pointed out gives you the answer all by itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Artin's Lemma of linear independence of characters](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M250.04/artinlemma.html) says that a set of distinct characters is linearly independent. The given equation manifestly states that the automorphisms $\sigma^i,i=0,1,2,3,$ are linearly dependent. Therefore they cannot be all distinct.
Thus the order of $\sigma$ is strictly less than $4$. On the other hand the order must be a factor of four. Therefore it is a factor of two.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/218394/11619).

Comment: Beautiful, as always :)

Comment: Nice. :) Thanks for recalling this theorem, I've almost forgotten about it, even though I asked the other question myself. :) Also, straightforward calculation shows that if $\sigma$ isn't identity to begin with, the characteristic is two. (Since if $\sigma$ isn't identity, we have for some $\alpha$ that $\alpha=\sigma^2(\alpha)=-\alpha$).

Comment: Thanks this theorem is so basic. my book (Dummit) says that this theorem is due to dededink instead Artin

Comment: @Gastón: Yes, I've seen (or at least heard) it linked to Dedekind as well. I don't know the history exactly. May be that most elegant proof is due to Artin, but the result itself was already know to Dedekind?

Comment: I wonder if is possible can solve this problem by the simple use of given identities

Answer (score 3):

Now that a nice solution has been given, let me give a direct solution,
at least when char. F $\neq 2$.

As Jim observed in the comments,
the minimal poly. of $\sigma$ divides $(X-1)(X^2 + 1)$.

Suppose now that the char. $\neq 2$.  Then $X - 1$ and $X^2 + 1$ are coprime, and so we may decompose $F$ into the direct sum of a space where $\sigma  = 1$ (the fixed field of $\sigma$) and of a space where $\sigma^2  + 1 = 0$.

Since the gcd. of $(X^2 -1)$ and $(X-1)(X^2 +1)$ equals $X-1$, we also
see that the fixed field of $\sigma^2$ equals the fixed field of $\sigma$.

Now if $\alpha$ lies in the space where $\sigma^2 + 1 = 0$, then $\sigma^2(\alpha^2) = (\sigma^2(\alpha))^2 = (-\alpha)^2 = \alpha^2,$ and so $\alpha^2$ 
is fixed by $\sigma^2$.  Thus by the preceding remark it is fixed by $\sigma$,
i.e. $\sigma(\alpha)^2 = \sigma(\alpha^2) = \alpha^2$.  But then $\sigma(\alpha)  = \pm \alpha$.  Thus $\sigma^2 - 1$ also acts by zero on the space where $\sigma^2 + 1$ acts by zero.  The only way this is possible is if this space
itself equals zero, i.e. if $F = F^{\sigma}$.

---

This argument is not so different to the general argument via independence of characters.  The key fact we used, beyond general linear algebra, is that 
$\sigma(\alpha^2) = \sigma(\alpha)^2$, which allows us to produce new eigenvalues from old.  More precisely, on the space where $\sigma^2 + 1 = 0,$
the eigenvalues are $\pm  i$.  So if $\alpha$ is an eigenvector for 
one of these eigenvalues, then $\alpha^2$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue
$-1$.  But this eigenvalue isn't allowed.  Thus $\pm i$ can't appear as eigenvalues after all.   (In the actual argument above, I didn't argue with eigenvalues because $F$ may not contain $4$th roots of unity.  But this eigenvalue computation is what is behind the argument, and is closely related 
to independence of characters.)